# How to prove independence from a word question

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Question: "You are recruiting students to participate in a study about alcohol consumption. Among all students, 30% have attend drunk, one-ﬁfth of whom (i.e. 6% overall) are still drinking. To meet the quota for your study, you select students at random until you have found 20 still drunk. Let X be the number of sober students that you ﬁnd before stopping. Let Y be the number of drunk students still drinking. Determine whether X and Y are independent. Explain your reasoning."

I'm not quite sure what explain means, but from past experiences, they usually want you to prove via theorems and what not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You need to show $P(X|Y)=P(X)$. We can model X as a [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) random variable where we will stop after 20 "failures" to find a dunk person.

If there are $N\gg 20$ students in the population, then the failure probability is $p \approx 1-\frac{Y}{B}$

Since $Y$ determines the distribution of $X$ you'd expect these to variables to be correlated, and hence not independent.